# Python on Windows 10: os.rename() cannot find a file that os.path.exists() finds?

Tags: python, windows, pathname

I'm wondering about `os.rename()`: Even though `os.path.exists()` says the file exists, `os.rename()` says it cannot find it. Here's the code snippet:

```
        try:
            if (os.path.exists(sourcePath)):
                print('Safe: %s does exist!' % sourcePath)
            os.rename (sourcePath, newPath)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error renaming "%s":' % sourcePath)
            raise e
```

Running this on a file named `Y:\home\Paul\PaulsBilder\images\..\import\batch0\2012-05  Neuruppin\12-05 - 0 2.JPG` yielded the following output:

```
Safe: Y:\home\Paul\PaulsBilder\images\..\import\batch0\2012-05  Neuruppin\12-05 - 0 2.JPG does exist!
Error renaming "Y:\home\Paul\PaulsBilder\images\..\import\batch0\2012-05  Neuruppin\12-05 - 0 2.JPG":
Traceback (most recent call last):
 :
WindowsError: [Error 3] Das System kann den angegebenen Pfad nicht finden
```

(German Windows: "The system cannot find the specified path.") I've been using this snippet some time now without issues, but probably never on filenames with spaces... But then, when I replace the spaces with underscores, the filename still can't be found.

Something else must be wrong, but what?

EDIT: Removing the `/../` component (by wrapping `os.normpath()` around it) does not help.

Comment: What happens if you remove `\images\..` from the path?

Comment: Are you doing this with multiple files in a loop?  What if you put the `os.rename` under the `if` so it won't execute unless the path exists?  Does it still try to run?

Comment: @BrenBarn, except I think `ERROR_PATH_NOT_FOUND` (3) should only occur in this context (i.e. calling `MoveFileEx`) for a bad path. If the source file can't be found the error should be `ERROR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` (2), and if the target name already exists the error should be `ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS` (183).

Comment: @eryksun: That may be.  My point is just that, if the code is running in a loop, the iteration where it prints "Safe" may not be the same iteration where the error is raised, which could mean some more effort is required to debug it.

Comment: possible that the path not found is from the newPath instead ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks a lot, Skycc, you're perfectly right: The error occurred because the directory of the new pathname did not exist. Silly me.

This one works - make sure `os.makedirs()` is only called once:

```
        try:
            if (os.path.exists(sourcePath)):
                print('Safe: %s does exist!' % sourcePath)
            (head, tail) = os.path.split(newPath)  # @UnusedVariable
            if (not os.path.exists(head)):
                os.makedirs(head)
            os.rename(sourcePath, newPath)
        except Exception as e:
            print('Error renaming "%s" to "%s":' % (sourcePath, newPath))
            raise e
```

Comment: glad you figure it out, Welcome :)